Is it possible to compress a tar ball with gzip/bzip2/xz after tar ball file has been created?
If we create a tar ball file by giving the following command
tar -cvf Docs.tar $HOME/Documents/*

then post creation of the tar ball is it possible to use gzip or bzip2 or xz or some other compression utility to compress the tar file?
I know that we can give the option --bzip2 or --xz or --gzip while creating the tar along with -cvf  option but what if that is not done. And after the tar is created then the compression is sought to be applied. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Recommend that you start thinking about how you can test such questions yourself. To be absolutely safe, you would copy your .tar file to another, safe directory, and then just run gzip2 my.tar and see what happens. Always do tests after you have created a safe backup.

Tarballs are compressed as a whole, and you can do this after they’ve been created by running them through a compressor:
gzip Docs.tar

will produce Docs.tar.gz which can then be processed as usual by versions of tar with support for compression.
Other compressors work similarly (xz Docs.tar, bzip2 Docs.tar etc.).
Historically, common tar implementations didn’t support compression directly, and this is how they had to be used. Usually this would involve pipes:
tar -cf - $HOME/Documents/* | gzip > Docs.tar.gz


Thanks. The reason that I ask was that I was going to use 7zip and rar compression to compress the tar ball. Wanted to know whether it will work or not.

Oh, OK — it’s always useful to explain the underlying reason... 7-zip and RAR are archivers, not purely compressors, and can’t be used in quite the same way with tar.
